# Angular ngSubmit doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is the following code:

```
<form data-ng-submit="ctrl.filter()" novalidate="true" class="search-filter ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse">
          <fieldset>
            <div class="search-filter-group">
              <div class="search-field-group">
                <div class="text-field">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Type some text" data-ng-model="ctrl.searchString" class="ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse">
                  <div data-ng-click="ctrl.resetFilter()" class="action-button reset-button">Reset</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <input type="submit" value="Find" data-ng-class="{disabled: !ctrl.canFilter()}" class="button">
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
```

But when I click by submit input 'ctrl.filter()' function doesn't be triggered, but if I add `data-ng-click="ctrl.filter()"` to my submit input it works. What's the trouble?

Comment: @lin that doesn't make sense...the submit event will never be triggered

Comment: Please provide a **runnable** [mcve].

Comment: What should I add? @charlietfl

Comment: No idea without seeing full example. Have never had problems using `ng-submit`

Comment: Did you try to use `ng-submit` ? instead of `data-ng-submit`?
And you should never use ng-click and ng-submit together. This from angular docs: `Warning: Be careful not to cause "double-submission" by using both the ngClick and ngSubmit handlers together. See the form directive documentation for a detailed discussion of when ngSubmit may be triggered.`
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit

Comment: As you can see I don't have ngSubmit with ngClick at the same time

Comment: it was referred to this in the question: `But when I click by submit input 'ctrl.filter()' function doesn't be triggered, but if I add data-ng-click="ctrl.filter()" to my submit input it works. What's the trouble?`
btw using `ng-submit` do you get your submit triggered?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: You have these classes because you copied the generated HTML source or because you really manually added them? `ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse`

Comment: I copied HTML from Chrome DevTools @quirimmo

Comment: What's your browser @malcoauri?

Comment: @MajidParvin last Chrome OS X

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="example" ng-app="StackM">
<div ng-controller="StackC as ctrl">
    <form data-ng-submit="ctrl.filter()" novalidate="true" class="search-filter ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse">
      <fieldset>
        <div class="search-filter-group">
          <div class="search-field-group">
            <div class="text-field">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Type some text" data-ng-model="ctrl.searchString" class="ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse">
              <div data-ng-click="ctrl.resetFilter()" class="action-button reset-button">Reset</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Find" data-ng-class="{disabled: !ctrl.canFilter()}" class="button">
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

```
<script>
angular.module("StackM", [])
    .controller("StackC", function($scope){
        this.filter = function(){
          var a = this.searchString
            debugger;
        }

    })
```

Comment: Try this code...This is working
Also you can see this working DOJO
http://dojo.telerik.com/aWOKaY/3

Please upvote my answer if this solves your issue